# How to manage nested class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple nested `ul` and `li` now i want o access just main child not all the children's how can i access?

Issue: I'm trying to toggle clicked `li` to `plus` with `minus` but right now all the children toggle but i want just clicked `li` should be toggle.

My Code:-

```js
$('.has-sub').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).find('a svg').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus')
});
```

```css
.product-category-nav h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product-category-nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.product-category-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #0d6efd;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a svg {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.product-category-nav ul.category-sub {
  display: none;
}

.product-category-nav .has-sub.active ul.category-sub {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.product-category-nav ul.category-sub li a {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-category-nav">
  <h4>PRODUCT CATEGORY </h4>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Healthcare & Medical <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu 1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">first menu 2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Food Service Disposables <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Hygiene & Cleaning <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Covid-19 Protection <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `find()` will traverse all child nodes in the DOM, affecting all where necessary.

To correct this behaviour in this case you can use `children()` as this only looks at direct child elements, not grandchildren, great-grandchildren etc.

```js
$('.has-sub').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).children('a').find('svg').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
});
```

```css
.product-category-nav h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product-category-nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.product-category-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #0d6efd;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a svg {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.product-category-nav ul.category-sub {
  display: none;
}

.product-category-nav .has-sub.active ul.category-sub {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.product-category-nav ul.category-sub li a {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-category-nav">
  <h4>PRODUCT CATEGORY </h4>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Healthcare & Medical <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu 1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">first menu 2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Food Service Disposables <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Hygiene & Cleaning <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Covid-19 Protection <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @RohitVerma,  please have a look at my solution and it may help. This solution: When you clicked on the children menu, it will close the parent menu.

Answer (score 1):

Example below:

use `$(">a svg",this)`

```js
$("li").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(">a svg",this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
});
```

```css
.product-category-nav h4 {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding: 0px 0px;
            line-height: 45px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
            color: #0d6efd;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul li a svg {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 18px;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul.category-sub {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav .has-sub.active ul.category-sub {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        
        .product-category-nav ul.category-sub li a {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 0px 15px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-category-nav">
  <h4>PRODUCT CATEGORY</h4>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub">
      <a href="#">Healthcare & Medical <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li>
          <a href="#">first menu 1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">first menu 2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
      <a href="#">Food Service Disposables <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li>
          <a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
      <a href="#">Hygiene & Cleaning <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li>
          <a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
      <a href="#">Covid-19 Protection <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li>
          <a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In your solution nested `+` on click closes parent.

Answer (score 1):

Use code eq(0) to trigger the first element of find().Like:

```
$(this).find('a svg:eq(0)').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
```

```js
$('.has-sub').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).find('a svg:eq(0)').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
});
```

```css
.product-category-nav h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product-category-nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.product-category-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #0d6efd;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-category-nav ul li a svg {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.product-category-nav ul.category-sub {
  display: none;
}

.product-category-nav .has-sub.active ul.category-sub {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.product-category-nav ul.category-sub li a {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-category-nav">
  <h4>PRODUCT CATEGORY </h4>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Healthcare & Medical <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu 1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">first menu 2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Food Service Disposables <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Hygiene & Cleaning <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Covid-19 Protection <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-sub">
        <li><a href="#">first menu <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```